# Handling Navigation on the page navigated to

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, navigation

My application requires that I navigate from one page to another in wpf on the click of a button, and pass a parameter with the URL like this :

```
 this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml?article="+textBoxContent.Text, UriKind.Relative));
```

Now, I want to retrieve this data on page2. There is a method like 'OnNavigatedTo' in Windows Phone 7 that we can override. How to do it in wpf?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In OnNavigatedTo method of Page2

```
    var article = navigationContext.Parameters["article"];
```